# Copy from one object to another - only values from common properties of their interfaces

Tags: typescript, clean-architecture

I have an interface (`interfaceA`) that has 2 properties and another one (`interfaceB`) that has 3 properties (*The numbers are just for example*).

I have created an object (type: `interfaceB`) and I would like to create another object (type: `interfaceA`) and copy only the values from the common properties from B to A.

- One solution is to copy all the fields and delete the third one, but I don't like that.
- Another solution is to create a new Object with only the properties that I need but I don't like that either.

In both solutions, if someone adds a property to one of the interfaces, I would have to add or delete the property in the assignment also.

Is there any solution to my problem?

I have created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1ssxrs?file=index.ts) to help you understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```js
function copyValues(objA: interfaceA, objB: interfaceB) {
  Object.entries(objB).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (objA.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      objA[key] = value;
    }
  });
}
```

*PS: If not, then it is not possible, you need to have the information of which keys objectA has at runtime - AFAIK there is no way to generate that from the types. You can get a type that represents what you want e.g. `Extract<keyof interfaceB, keyof interfaceA>` but there is no way to get that into a runtime-usable form.*

Comment: Nope, because `hasOwnProperty` doesn't work if the `objectA` has not instantiated with the right properties in the first place.

Comment: What you want is not possible then, you need to have the information of which keys `objectA` has at runtime - AFAIK there is no way to generate that from the types. You can get a type that represents what you want e.g. `Extract<keyof interfaceB, keyof interfaceA>` but there is no way to get that into a runtime-usable form.